# zend getrequest ajax

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
    $ajaxContext->addActionContext('view', 'html');
    $ajaxContext->initContext();
}
```

how does this actually work... my ajax get page is  `local.maker/profile/check`

i got ajax to work fine but i dont know what to edit from the above...

```
$ajaxContext->addActionContext('???', 'html');
```

ps.. i am requesting a json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code to use AJAX context helper.

In your controller create a preDispatch method to set up your contexts like this:

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    $this->_helper->ajaxContext()
                  ->addActionContext('index', array('json', 'html'))
                  ->addActionContext('anotheraction', 'json')
                  ->initContext();
}
```

And then in you action methods use:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    if ($this->_helper->ajaxContext()->getCurrentContext() == 'json') {
        // ajax code here
    } else {
        // non ajax code here
    }
}
```

Also in your ajax request you must use the variable format to set the current context, for example

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index/format/json
```

to request a json response.

Note: The context switcher automatically disables the layout and view, any view variable set in the controller will automatically be encoded into a json string and sent.

I hope this helps

Kind regards

Garry

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the example . It has everything what you are looking for .

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.ajaxcontext

```
addActionContext( <action>, <format>);
```

Can request comment/process/format/json or via query variable . See the example .